# How do I efficiently maintain a large dictionary in memory in Python?

Tags: python

If I’d like to maintain a mapping with a million key-value pairs, what’s the most space-efficient way to do it in Python?

Comment: Why not a dictionary? You may want to review the optimization notes for your use-case: https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictnotes.txt

Comment: What is the nature of your key value pairs? Do you want better than linear time lookups, or is memory efficiency a greater concern? Why won't a `dict` object work for you?

Comment: A pandas dataframe is said to work correctly with 100 million rows, so that could be another way... (indexed, index kept unique...) But it indeed depends on what values you want to use. List scalar or lists?